# genitive case (difficult surnames)

Tags: possessives

When we write difficult surnames, e.g. Novak Djokovic, is it neccessary to use 's in the genitive case? Is it correct to write Novak Djokovic match-ball, or we must write Novak Djokovic's match-ball (that is difficult to pronounce)?

Comment: Why is it so difficult to pronounce? If you can say *"itches"*, can't you say *"Djokovic's"*?

Comment: I don't know, sometimes they don't write's

Comment: e.g. "It was a decent match," Murray said of the Djokovic match. (BBC). It seems difficult to pronounce to me but that's not my mother tongue.

Comment: "The X match" has nothing to do with how difficult the surname is. You will find it used with any name at all. And not with just matches, either.

Comment: Than with surnames in general is not neccessary to use 's? E.g. It's the same to use: "Obama's presidential campaign" or "Obama presidential campaign"?

Comment: These are two entirely different constructions, which often have very nearly the same meaning. But the _the Obama campaign_ construction (which requires "the", by the way) is limited in unobvious ways: I might say _the Johnson house_ (though that sounds a rather American phrase to me) but I wouldn't say _the Johnson car_.

Comment: ... And 'the Novak Djokovic car' isn't correct; you certainly need 'Novak Djokovic's car'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you sue about that, *the Novak Djokovic car is speeding round the corner* seems fine to me?

Comment: _The Djokovic match_ is not a match that _belongs_ to Djokovic, it's a match that _involves_ Djokovic. The same goes for _the Obama campaign_. That's why there's no possessive.

Comment: @Araucaria While nouns used attributively are often an acceptable alternative – indeed often a preferable alternative – to the 'Saxon genitive', their use as an indication of true ownership is rarely if ever considered acceptable. Thus one could acceptably write 'The dogs' home is quite close to Leigh Dogs Home', or 'The travellers' wallets were found, still containing their travellers cheques'.

Comment: @HON Just because nobody has clearly stated it before in the comments here: _the Ðoković match_ and _the Obama campaign_ do **not** contain possessives at all. The construction here uses [noun adjuncts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) instead, which are semantically very similar to, but grammatically entirely different from, possessives. The fact that these are last names is irrelevant: _the tennis match_ and _the election campaign_ use regular nouns in the same way.

Answer (score -1):

The grammatically correct form would be "Novak Djokovic's match ball." I suppose that the "'s" could potentially be omitted in an effort to save time/space. The only real irregularity that I know of when it comes to the English genitive case is when the word ends in an "s," in which case you can either use the "'s" or just the apostrophe (both are now considered correct- just the apostrophe is almost considered a little old-fashioned though)

Comment: Does the word (spelling) have to end in an _s_, or does the pronunciation have to end in an _s_? Because Djokovic fits the latter, not the first.

Comment: @oerkelens: it actually ends in a "ch". [See this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nDdtvbu8hw).